# Store previous search criteria using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have created a web application which returns a list of products. On this page it allows users to search for a range of different search criteria.

Once a user searches and the results are returned to the table on the page a user can then edit a product. However upon returning to the product listing page the page just reloads, and shows all products again.

I would like to know what the best way would be to keep the search results, and upon returning to the search page it keeps the previous criteria.

I have found a few posts on stack exchange 
- [Best way to store previous search criteria in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253701/best-way-to-store-previous-search-criteria-in-asp-net) - is probaly one of the better ones.

Does any one know how i could go about keeping the search criteria, so when a user returns to the search page, the previous search criteria and results stay the same.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entire search can be represented through query string, then it makes perfect sense to store that query string (or search criteria) in a cookie. Assuming that cookies are turned on of course.

When user navigates to the search page, you can read the query string from the cookie and return relevant results.

Client side state is a good way forward in systems with high load. You don't want to be storing state on a server if you have hundreds of concurrent users.

**Edit**

OK, say you decide to store results in the session. What are the problems with that? Your results might no longer be relevant. Something might change in the underlying data store and you will end up displaying inaccurate data.

Say you end up storing fairly large result set in memory - 100kb per user. Assuming you have two hundred of concurrent users, you are already looking at a minimum of 100kb * 200. That's under 20MB of storage, excluding other data, which you are likely to store in a session. As your system grows, it'll become expensive to scale.

On other hand, if you store search criteria on a client, then you can easily scale up to thousands of users. All you have to do, is retrieve their search criteria from a cookie and re-execute it.

I personally would look for a very good reason to store data in a session state. I.e. storing user sensitive data.

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253701/best-way-to-store-previous-search-criteria-in-asp-net) - yes it'll work, but as I've already said, it won't scale too well if you decide to store results on the server. Also, in the likely event of application pool being restarted or IIS being restarted, you will lose the search criteria.

Comment: I have considered using the query string way. What are your thoughts on storing in a session as per the post i found previously?

Comment: Great, appreciate your answer. A clear honest opinion :) Looks like query string will be the way forward ;)

Comment: If not the query string, then the key value pair, which you can then turn into a query string. You are welcome.

Comment: do you have a link for the key value pair solution at all?